# Building a Python Web application in jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, build, continuous-deployment

I want to **build an existing Python web application in jenkins, just like building a java application using Maven.**
Is it possible or not? if possible, please help me with necessary configurations to *build and Continuous Deployment of the same application*.

Comment: where's your exact problem?

Comment: I'm new to python. I didn't find a proper solution to build through jenkins. That's the problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Options 1)** without using docker

1. Choose `Free Style project` when create jenkins job
2. Configure the `Source code management` section to tell jenkins where to fetch the source code,
3. Write the build commands you used by manual in `build` section.
4. If your jenkins slave not installed Python and jenkins server not support to install Python on jenkins slave, you need to write commands in 'build' section to install Python,pip needed for build on jenkins slave.

**Option 2)** using docker

1. Build a docker image with all requried soft and tool installed and configured to supply a build enviroment  
   (You can search there is exist docker image can meet your requirement on docker image hub before build image yourself? )
2. Upload the image to docker image hub
3. Install docker engine on jenkins slave
4. Create `Free style project`
5. Congiure `Source Code Management` section
6. Write docker command in  `Build` section to pull docker image and start a docker container, execute build command inside container

Comment: hi yong, thanks for the valuable answer. By the way, in option 1(your answer), in  **Build** section of jenkins, which option do i need to choose? Either  **virtualenv builder**  or **execute windows batch command**

Comment: I'm not familiar with virtualenv builder, so I will choose execute windows batch command.  but I heard something like virtualenv to build a Python evnrionment, i'm  not sure the virtualenv builder is it.  you need to investigate that.

Comment: Thanks **yong**. I will do further investigation on the same.